# Android Kotlin Recyclerview inside fragment is null

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't get my Recycleview inside my fragment to work. I've tried moving the recyclerview `adapter` and `layout` code to `onViewCreated` but that didn't work either.

Does anybody have an idea to what the problem could be?

**Main Activity**

```
...
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        loadFragment(NewsFragment()) // Show the news fragment by default
        initBottomNavigation()
}
...
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
}
...
```

**NewsAdapter**

```
class NewsAdapter(private val newsItems: List<NewsItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        context = parent.context

        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_list_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = newsItems.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) =
        holder.bind(newsItems[position])

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(newsItem: NewsItem) {

        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_news.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvNewsItems"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <include
            layout="@layout/news_list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**NewsFragment**

```
class NewsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val newsItems = arrayListOf<NewsItem>()
    private val newsAdapter = NewsAdapter(newsItems)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (container != null) {
            container.rootView.rvNewsItems.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
            container.rootView.rvNewsItems.adapter = newsAdapter
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        btnLike.setOnClickListener {
            val color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorPrimary, null);
            btnLike.setColorFilter(color)
        }
    }

}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.johanvanderlindenapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0"

    // Material widgets
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
}
```

**EDIT**
I have removed the include inside the recycleview shown above, still receive the error.

Comment: `loadFragment(NewsFragment()) // Show the news fragment by default` <-- check #9 in https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Not the source of my error, but still very nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `vindViewById` instead of `synthetic` turned out to solve the problem.

My news fragment now looks like this:

```
class NewsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val newsItems = arrayListOf<NewsItem>()
    private val newsAdapter = NewsAdapter(newsItems)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false)
        val rvNewsItems = view.findViewById(R.id.rvNewsItems) as RecyclerView

        rvNewsItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvNewsItems.adapter = newsAdapter

        return view
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewsFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvNewsItems"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>





class NewsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val newsItems = arrayListOf<NewsItem>()
    private val newsAdapter : NewsAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        container.rootView.rvNewsItems.adapter = newsAdapter
        container.rootView.rvNewsItems.adapter as NewsAdapter).submitList(newsItems)

    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    btnLike.setOnClickListener {
        val color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorPrimary, null);
        btnLike.setColorFilter(color)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't run the `submitList` part. Android Studio gives an `Unexpected tokens` error.

Comment: can you try this ->

val newsAdapter = NewsAdapter(newsItems)

Comment: is the list has any object?

Comment: If I add things to the list and notify to the adapter, I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you remove submitList? Can you sure is list has object and can you check viewHolder fired?

Comment: I removed `submitList`. The list has objects, but viewHolder is not fired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205197/discussion-between-bvdl-and-enderkoca).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `<include />` tag to show your list items. Your `ViewHolder` class takes care of instantiating your list items for you. Simply remove the `include` tag in your **fragment_news.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvNewsItems"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Also, make sure your `newsItems` is not empty. Otherwise, it will show you an empty view. If you wish to add items to your `newsItems`, don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter to reflect the changes.

Comment: I have removed the include following @enderkoca's answer. The problem still persists though.

Comment: @BvdL how are you populating the recycler view?

Comment: Adding objects to the `newsItems` list and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the `newsAdapter`